# A function in javascript to find the closest number to a certain threshold (Closest left) number in array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, function

I am writing a function to find a number in an array like I have 999 the greatest number but that is not present in array so I want the only one number which is nearby 999 like 899 or 951 or 50 even if 5 is bigger than other number which is present in the array if 999 is not there how I can do that please help.

```js
let a = [5, 5, 9, 5, 6, 888, 98, 2, 6];

a.map(function (a) {
  return a >= 900;
});
```

I just need one number in output

Comment: It is not so clear what exactly do you want? Do you want the largest number in an array?

Comment: Get the "nearby" or get the max? Because say for example your "greatest number" is 999 and it doesn't exist in the array but 998 and 1500 do, should you get 998 or 1500? 1500 is the max number in the array but 998 is closer to 999.

Comment: I'd assume 998, as that's only 1 off, not 501 off? `reduce` with a distance check and done.

Comment: @dork suppose that I have a predefined number 600 so we can't take number more than 600 so we need a number which should be less than 600 but it should be the greater then other values which is present in array and less then 600 even though 900 is the but I can't take this number.

Answer (score 2):

If You Want The Closest Left Side Number :

```js
let a = [5, 5, 9, 5, 6, 888, 98, 2, 6];
let target = 885; // Our Target
 function closestLeftSide(array,target){
    let filtered = a.filter(x=>x<=target); // discard all bigger numbers
    let closest = filtered[0]; // initialaze first closest
    for(number of filtered){
         closest = Math.abs(target-number)<=Math.abs(target-closest)?number:closest;
    }
    return closest
 }
console.log(closestLeftSide(a,target))
```

if you want to find the most closest number in array to a given number :

```js
let a = [5, 5, 9, 5, 6, 888, 98, 2, 6];
let target = 4;
let closest = a[0];

for(number of a){
    closest = (Math.abs(target - number) <= Math.abs(target - closest))? number:closest;
}
console.log(closest)
```

Comment: Do note that the request is about a function, so remember to actually make your answer show a function (And probably code that calls it).

Answer (score 1):

You can [.reduce() your list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) updating a "running result" as you iterate over all elements in the array, and only update it if it's closer to your desired value than the previous running result:

```js
function findClosest(list, targetValue) {
  const better = (running, element) => 
    Math.abs(targetValue - element) < Math.abs(targetValue - running);

  return list.reduce(
    (running, element) => better(running, element) ? element : running,
    list[0]
  );
}

const someList = [5, 5, 1200, 9, 5, 6, 888, 98, 2, 6];
const someValue = 900;

console.log(
  `Closest value to ${someValue}: ${findClosest(someList, someValue)}`
);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to maximum number that is less than an upper bound, then:

```
const target = 700;
let a = [5, 5, 9, 5, 6, 888, 98, 2, 6];

console.log(findMaxWithUpperBound(a, target));

function findMaxWithUpperBound(list: number[], upperBound: number) {
  let max = list[0];

  list.forEach((n) => {
    if (n > max && n < upperBound) {
      max = n;
    }
  });

  return max;
}
```

Comment: Now you just need to wrap that code into a function, not leave it as bare code.